# What is the difference between "I will write the letter tomorrow" and "I will have written the letter tomorrow"?

Tags: future-perfect

What is the difference between "I will have written the letter tomorrow" and "I will write the letter tomorrow"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say **I will write the letter tomorrow** is a plain statement of intent in which you look forward at the present moment to an act you plan to carry out in the future.

To say **I will have written the letter tomorrow** is a way of looking back from a future point at an intended action that lies between the present and that future point.

We use this construction particularly for reassurance, whether to ourselves or a third party.

For example, a soldier might reflect: **At this time tomorrow I will have completed my tour of duty**.

And a builder might reassure an anxious householder: **The house repairs will have been completed by tomorrow evening.**

So the difference lies not in the future action itself but in the way that the speaker regards it - and the speaker's purpose.

Which construction you would prefer really depends on the context.

Comment: You may want to note that if the person writes the letter today, then "I will have written the letter tomorrow" is still a true statement, but "I will write the letter tomorrow" is false.